# Committing changes on Visual Studio Tools for Git is really slow

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, bitbucket

I'm pretty sure the slowness issue when you committing changes in VS Team Explorer now becomes a real pain for many developers, I was wondering if anyone come across the same issue ? or have any work around this problem ?

The slowness is only when you commit your changes but it is fast when it passes this stage and you Sync it.

[image: Just right here, whenever you click on commit button]

Comment: Can you tell us more about what sorts of files you have in your project?  Do you have a lot of binaries?

Comment: Does it take a long time to commit, after you press the button?  Or does it take a long time for the commit button to become enabled?

Comment: @Edward Thomson yeah it takes long time after I press the "commit" button. minimum 2~3 minutes

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, it doesn't matter what file I have ready to be committed , even if I choose a simple single html file, it takes a long time.

Comment: The only thing I can potentially suggest is that you do a garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks both for the tips.

Comment: Git bash is your friend ;)

Comment: Did you ever find and answerino for this. My commit it taking well over 5 minutes.. a bit annoying. When I use git bash it is intantino

Comment: Yes you need to clear the git from very old and large data alternatively you could start a new repository, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository

Answer (score 1):

Commit shouldn't be slow as it is completely local. Try to compact the local git database using one of the many git gui tools. I like "git extensions" and this one: https://git-for-windows.github.io. The last tool has a menu choice to compact the database which removes all old and loose objects from the repository making it faster.